# Proper way to integrate these functions into a main script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a script that will read the contents of multiple .xml files, make a webservice request, and log if that request was successful or not. As of right now I have 3 functions - one that outputs the contents of the folders for validation, one that reads the contents of the files, and one that makes the request from the contents of these files. On their own they work exactly as I need them to, but the purpose of my project is to automate this process so that I can put the files in this specified directory and run the script to make all the webservice calls. How would I structure my `def main()` function to accomplish this?

```
import os
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


RESEND_FILES = os.path.join("resend_files")



def main():
    get_xml_list()
    read_file()
    resend(?)


def resend(data):
    out = open('output.xml', 'w')
    url = 'https://url.com/path/to/wsdl?wsdl'
    headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
    response = requests.post(url,
                             data=data,
                             headers=headers,
                             verify=False,
                             auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
                             )

    out.write(response.text)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(open("output.xml"), "xml")
    xml_content = bs.prettify()
    out.write(xml_content)
    print(xml_content)


def get_xml_list():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(RESEND_FILES):
        level = root.replace(RESEND_FILES, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = ' ' * 4 * level
        print('{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
        subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
        for f in files:
            print('{}{}'.format(subindent, f))


def read_file():
    for dirPath, foldersInDir, fileName in os.walk(RESEND_FILES):
        if fileName is not []:
            for file in fileName:
                loc = os.sep.join([dirPath, file])
                txt = open(loc)
                data = txt.read()
                return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are asking how to pass the return value of `read_file` to `resend`?

Comment: There is a comment at `def read_file():` which says "prints out". What does that mean? The function doesn't print anything.

Comment: That comment was when I only had it printing the contents of the files. I need to return the values of each file to the `resend()` function so that the contents of the .xml files I'm reading gets sent as a webservice call.

Comment: But you are already using the return values from functions and passing them to other functions many times in your code. What's the difficulty for you to do it once more in `main`?

Comment: Well I tried `resend(read_file())` in the `main` but it only attempted to send the contents one of the 5 files I have in the desired folder. If I only run the `read_file()` function it will read/print the contents of all 5.

Comment: Did you mean to return a list (or other container) of contents of multiple files from `read_file` instead of the contents of a single file?

Comment: I'm sure I've messed this up, but my intention is to iterate through each file, return the contents one by one as `data` and pass it through the `resend()` function to make the web service call.

Answer (score 0):

If you change read_file to be a generator function so that it can be iterated ..

```
def read_file():
    for dirPath, foldersInDir, fileName in os.walk(RESEND_FILES):
        if fileName is not []:
            for file in fileName:
                loc = os.sep.join([dirPath, file])
                txt = open(loc)
                data = txt.read()
                yield data
```

Then in main you could have:

```
    for data in read_file():
        resend(data)
```

You may have to make other changes though.